# How can I redirect users to different pages based on session/form data is valid or not in PHP?

Tags: php

I am working with a very simple form and trying to learn php. I have sessions working and post data working but I am trying to redirect the user to next page if the data is valid. I am running some validation which also I am successful with so far but only thing I am not finding is how to go to the next page if the data that they entered in the form is valid.If not it is already printing an error.  I am very new to this so any help would be appreciated.

```
$nameErr = "";
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
            if(empty($_POST["fname"])){
                $nameErr = "name is required";
            }
        }
```

This is how my form looks like. I know I have to change something in the "action" part of the form as of right now it is printing to the same but not sure what. Can I write a if statement or something?

```
<form  method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

  <label for="fname">FirstName:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="Enter First Name">
     <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
```

Comment: A few notes: Do not use `PHP_SELF` as this is unsafe, at least clean the variable before echoing it. Also, while @Parag Tyagi does have the correct answer, and it is a good idea when using PHP `header` but  you need to have no output before the `header` and you really should add a `die();` statement afterward the header to ensure the rest of the script does not fire, in this instance.

Comment: Make sense. It was giving me an error. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **[PHP header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)**

```
header("Location: /example/par1/");
exit();
```

**In your case:**

```
$nameErr = "";
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    if(empty($_POST["fname"]))
    {
        $nameErr = "name is required";
    }
    else
    {
        // If validation success, then redirect
        header("Location: http://www.google.com/");
        exit();
    }
}
```

**Note:**

Yes, as **@Andrei P** said in the comments there shouldn't be anything before the `header()` is called. To be more precise, header functions should be called just after PHP opening tag `<?php`. For example,

```
<?php
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
exit;
```

Below will give you an **error**

```
<html>
<?php
/* This will give an error. Note the output
 * above, which is before the header() call */
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
exit;
?>
```

For more info can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php).

Comment: Very important to mention that you cannot output anything before the header. Not even whitespace.

Comment: Just to clarify. I did read about this but not sure how to implement. So this will go the location when the data is valid?

Comment: Yes. It make sense. Much appreciated.

Comment: if `$_POST['fname']` is not empty, the header will be loaded and the page will be redirected.

Comment: @AndreiP. Yes, thankyou. Added a small note in answer.